# Не сохраняются cookies

Tags: php

Не сохраняются cookies, когда перехожу между страницами. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так. Заранее спасибо за ответ и уделенное время!

Страница **test.php**

```
    <?php
$str = "Добро пожаловать, новичок!";
if(isset($_COOKIE['flag'])) {
    $str = "С возвращением, дружище";
} else {
    setcookie('flag', "1", time() + 60 * 60 * 10);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Страница index_test.php</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Страница index_test.php</h1>
<a href="page_test.php"> Страница page_test.php </a>
<br><br>
<p> Привет, <?php echo $name; ?></p>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Страница **index_test.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) && (!empty($_POST['name']))) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    setcookie('name', $name, time() + 60 * 60 * 10);
} elseif (isset($_COOKIE['name'])) {
    $name = $_COOKIE['name'];
}
else {
    $name = "Гость";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Страница index_test.php</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Страница index_test.php</h1>
        <a href="page_test.php"> Страница page_test.php </a>
        <br><br>
        <p> Привет, <?php echo $name; ?></p>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Страница **page_test.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['name'])) {
   setcookie('name', '', time() + 60 * 60 * 10);
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title> Страница page_test.php</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Страница page_test.php</h1>
<a href="index_test.php"> Страница index_test.php</a>
<br><br>
<p> Привет, куки удалены</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Загляните в лог ошибок сервера. Загляните в консоль браузера и в раздел сеть инструментов разработчика. Если у вас в файле test.php первая строка действительно с ведущими пробелами, то уберите все пробелы перед `<`. Файлы сохраняйте в формате `UTF-8 без BOM`, если работает в кодировке UTF-8.

Comment: Если ни чего не помогает, замените во всех файлах `time() + 60 * 60 * 10` на `0`.

Comment: А `session_start` уже не надо писать?

Comment: @u_mulder, для печенек сессии?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю проблема в "Области видимости" куки, можно прочитать тут:  https://www.php.net/setcookie.
Можно попробовать задать куку так:

```
setcookie("Имя куки", "значение куки", time()+36000, "/");
```

или

```
setcookie("Имя куки", "значение куки", time()+36000, "/",'Ваш домен');
```

Comment: Не совсем уловил вашу мысль или вы не поняли суть моей проблемы. Когда я захожу впервые на test.php, то устанавливаю там имя, которое хранится в cookies. Затем перехожу на страницы index_test.php и page_test.php и имя по моей задумке должно сохраняться. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @turutum суть проблемы понятна, вы прочитали документацию?
Вы можете проверить сохраняется ли куки в файле test.php - `print_r($_COOKIE['flag']);`
если в файле test.php  выводится кука но не получаете данную куку в  index_test.php и page_test.php - это значит что у вас кука задаётся только для файла test.php т.е проблема в области видимости куки. Для проверки данной ситуации я предложил вставить куки для всего домена!
`setcookie("Имя куки", "значение куки", time()+36000, "/");`